# react-syntax-highlighter new line in Clojure code sample

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-highlighting

Hi I cannot find anywhere on how to add new lines into this code sample:

```
<SyntaxHighlighter language='clojure' style={darcula} showLineNumbers={true} wrapLines={true}> 
  (def a 2) *add a new line break here* 
  (def b 3)
</SyntaxHighlighter>
```

Using:

import SyntaxHighlighter from 'react-syntax-highlighter';
import { darcula, docco } from 'react-syntax-highlighter/styles/hljs';

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution that I've found is to do it this way:

```
<SyntaxHighlighter language='clojure' style={darcula} showLineNumbers={true} wrapLines={true}>
        {`first line \nsecond line`}
</SyntaxHighlighter>
```

Also you can put text into the const

```
const code = `(def a 2) *add a new line break here*
(def b 3)`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate component called CodeBlock:

```
const CodeBlock: React.FC<{ codestring: string }> = ({ codestring }) => {
  return (
    <SyntaxHighlighter
      language="clojure"
      style={darcula}
      showLineNumbers>
      {codestring}
    </SyntaxHighlighter>
  );
};
```

In order to make `codestring` take up multiple lines, you need to create a string using backticks (`) and pass it to the component as a prop.

```
 var code = `(def a 2)
(def b 3)`;

  return (
    <div className="w-1/2 bg-blue-700">
      <CodeBlock codestring={code} />
    </div>
  );
```

Output:

[image]